# React Component onClick wont work

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack

im new to react in nodejs. I used react documentation on onClick handler but it wont work for me. I've been searching all around and nothing seems to work.

express routes :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var React = require('react');
var ReactDomServer = require('react-dom/server');
var Component = require("../public/javascripts/component.jsx");

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  var html = ReactDomServer.renderToString (
    React.createElement (Component)
  );
  res.send(html);
});

module.exports = router;
```

component.jsx

```
var React = require('react');

module.exports = class SayHello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    alert("Test");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>
        Say hello
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your react code works fine for me.

Comment: @AanchalSharma but it wont handle the click

Comment: Well I tried your code on codepen and it worked fine. Why don't you try console.log instead of alert?

Comment: @AanchalSharma still doesnt work, do u use webpack?

Comment: you don't have to create another instance of a function you can just pass the refference like this: `<button onClick={this.handleClick}>`

Comment: @Sag1v doesnt work either

Comment: @FarellSujanto i didn't say this is the solution. I just pointed out that you don't need to create an instance of a function to invoke another function, you can just pass a reference of the `handleClick` function. creating instances of function inside the render method can let you to a performance hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReactDomServer` would only generate the HTML strings for the component... and that make only make your pages at server...
in order to add event listener.you still need client side code.

fake code:
--server side--

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  var html = ReactDomServer.renderToString (
    <div id="root"><Component/><script src="client-code.js"></script></div>
  );
  res.send(html);
});
```

--client side--

```
ReactDOM.render(<Component/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

the below code shows the difference between server-render and client-render.you can modify a few and add a .html then open in browser.

```
class SayHello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this
      .handleClick
      .bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    alert("Test");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        Say hello
      </button>
    );
  }
};
var test = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<SayHello/>);
document
  .getElementById('root')
  .innerHTML = test + '<button onclick="window.clientRender()">client render</button>';

window.clientRender = function() {
  ReactDOM.render((<SayHello/>), root);
};
```